# magento 1.9 How to set the size of the photo of all products

Tags: magento-1.9

I have a problem in **picture of product**

When a  **product`s photo is small**, the site can not enlarge the image
The site is a little screwed up and photos of small and large products can be seen
How to set the size of the photo of all products?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `init($_product, 'image')` instead of `init($_product, 'small_image')`

```
Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image')->resize(150)
```

For exemple in category page : `app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/template/catalog/product/list.phtml`

```
...
<a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'image'), null, true) ?>" class="product-image">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image')->resize(150, 150); ?>" alt="" />
</a>
...
```